# How to determine if XElement.Elements() contains a node with a specific name?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, .net-3.5

For example for the following XML

```
 <Order>
  <Phone>1254</Phone>
  <City>City1</City>
  <State>State</State>
 </Order>
```

I might want to find out whether the XElement contains "City" Node or not.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Just use the other overload for [Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975.aspx).

```
bool hasCity = OrderXml.Elements("City").Any();
```

Comment: Or use Descendants("MyNode").Any() if you don't care about where it is in the tree.

Comment: CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Any'

Comment: @AlanBaljeu add "using System.Linq" at the top of the file.  This allows the extension method System.Linq.Enumerable.Any to be used.

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while since I did XLinq, but here goes my WAG:

```
from x in XDocument
where x.Elements("City").Count > 0
select x
```

;

Answer (score 2):

David's is the best but if you want you can write your own predicate if you need some custom logic `OrderXML.Elements("City").Exists(x=>x.Name =="City")`